# Go lang service and PostgreSQL via Docker ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-swarm

I have got a resources release problem.

1. PostgreSQL runs on a server 1.
2. Go lang service runs on a server 2 in a Docker container.
3. There is an ssh tunnel Docker container for a connection between the database and the service. It does not know anything except ssh.

Docker is in swarm mode.

The service (2) connects to the database via golang database/sql library. I call `sql.Open()`, `driverName = "postgres"`. Then everything is ok. In some time, may be in 30 minutes, `(*DB) Query()` returns an error `read: connection reset by peer`. If I call `(*DB) Ping()` previously, `Ping()` does not return an error, but the next call `Query()` does.

If I call `Query()` again in some time, a new connection is created. I can see it in a `select * from pg_stat_activity;` query in the database  (`state = idle`). But the previous connection has not been removed.

So I call `(*DB) Close()`, create a new DB object and call `sql.Open()`.

> Close closes the database, releasing any open resources.

(https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Conn.Close)

But after the `Close` call I can still see the connection in a `select * from pg_stat_activity;` query in the database (`state = idle`).
I see the bad connection and the new one.

As the result there is a resources leak.

What is the correct way to handle a `read: connection reset by peer` error? Why have I got this error?

Comment: It seems to be an idle timeout issue: https://success.docker.com/article/ipvs-connection-timeout-issue

Comment: It is an open issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33685